# TimePickerDialog doesn't show properly in Android 6

Tags: android, android-layout, timepickerdialog

i'm using DatePickerDialog to select time on my app. When I run my app on a device with Android 5 as OS the dialog shows properly, meanwhile if i run my app on a device with Android 6 this is what the dialog looks like:

[image]

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue changing the way that the TimePickerDialog was being created.

I had this code :

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    return new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), myTimeListener, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
```

I changed the 2nd line for this one:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    return new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), R.style.AppTheme,  myTimeListener, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
```